# abort redundant jenkins builds except master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using jenkins pipelines, and have this `disableConcurrentBuilds` set - which right now if someone pushes a commit to a branch or pull request that is building, jenkins will cancel the existing build and start on the latest commit.

This is great for branches and pull requests, but I don't want this to happen to `master`

How do I alter `disableConcurrentBuilds` s.t. that it doesn't apply to `master`?

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)
  }
```

As an aside - where't the documentation for `disableConcurrentBuilds` - I see it here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/, but it doesn't tell me what options are available. Nothing about `abortPrevious` on that page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can´t do this, unless you have two jenkins jobs (one with `disableConcurrentBuilds` and another without it).

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/blob/ce9c4ba4ade3e06b1b9c320548cf2d6d33bcadea/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/properties/DisableConcurrentBuildsJobProperty.java) seems that `abortPrevious` is the only option available.

Comment: Is this idea even possible?  My app has one Jenkinsfile and in that is only one pipeline.  Even if Jenkinsfile has some way to configure multiple pipelines (which i'm not sure it can) the jenkins web UI that configure the job only allows me to set "Script path" which is currently Jenkinsfile -- there's no way to configure an option to use a different pipeline in there

Comment: I'll try to explain it better.

You should have 2 jenkinsfiles with the same steps, one with `disableConcurrentBuilds` and another without it.

Then, in the web UI you should create two jobs, one with each pipeline.

If you are using some kind of webhook, you should have two: one to build master and the other to build everything but master.